# How to integrate addthis in react applications?

Tags: reactjs, social-media

I need to be able to share the url of my page, through facebook, twitter, linkedIn. I also need to get the total sharecount through all of these. I was suggested to use the addThis plugin. But I do not see any documentation on how to use it in react applications. Please help!

Comment: check this out https://github.com/olahol/react-social, is that you need ?

Comment: No, I need to integrate addThis plugin to my react application

Comment: AddThis is proprietary, and it seems like their payment/funding model has evolved a bit over the years.  Do you want to have to change subscription, payment, etc., info every few months/years?  Why don't you try something free and open source?  Take a look at this project (disclaimer: I'm involved with it): [GitHub: Social Share URLs](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls) 100% free.